# Large products of a matrix-valued function

Tags: matrix, products

I have a $3\times 3$ matrix valued function $f(x)$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I want to perform the following:

$$\prod_{k=a}^b f(k),$$

where $a,b$ are known, but I cant seem to get Mathematica to do it. Any ideas?

I know I have to use `.`. instead of `*`, but I want something similar to

```
Product[f[k],{k,a,b}]
```

Clearly this won't work since `Product` works on $\mathbb{C}$ only (at least as far as my knowledge goes)

I have tried

```
Dot[f[k],{k,a,b}]
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: If `a,b` are known, then `Fold[Dot, Table[f[x], {x, a, b}]]` will work.

Comment: Try `Dot @@ Table[f[j], {j, a, b}]`

Comment: `Dot @@ (f /@ Range[a, b])`

Comment: `SetAttributes[f, Listable]; Dot @@ f@Range[a, b]`

Comment: "Put on hold". The mind boggles!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bunch of comments with upvotes. So, to sum up:

`PatrickStevens` says to `Fold` `Dot` over the `List` of `f[x]`'s

```
Fold[Dot, Table[f[x], {x, a, b}]]
```

`Hubble07` says to try `Apply`ing `Dot` to the `Table` of `f[x]`'s.

```
Dot @@ Table[f[x], {x, a, b}]
```

`belisarius` says to `Apply` `Dot` to `f` `Map`ped over the `Range`:

```
Dot @@ f /@ Range[a, b]
```

or to make the function `f` `Listable`:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable];
Dot @@ f@Range[a, b]
```

One more version:

```
Fold[Dot, Array[f, b - a + 1, a]]
Dot @@ Array[f, b - a + 1, a]
Array[f, b - a + 1, a, Dot]
```

Comment: Do all of these methods result in the full list of matrices being put into memory simultaneously?

Comment: @ComptonScattering. I believe so. You want something that generates the matrices on the fly as they're multiplied together? Maybe something like `Fold[#1.f[#2] &, f[a], Range[a + 1, b]]`? Or maybe it should be `Fold[f[#2].#1 &, f[a], Range[a + 1, b]]`; order matters of course,

Comment: I see what you have done. This has been very useful for me to understand. Thank you.